# Getting started with silverlight/facebook development

Tags: c#, silverlight, facebook

Is there any very simple sample applications to get started with facebook dev?

I just want to know how I would connect to facebook through silverlight, get the authentication stuff out of the way and then develop, debug and test my applications.

Do I need to be connected to a server which connects to facebook or can I do the development from my own PC which can 'talk' to facebook?

I'm also a bit worried about the updating APIs. Some of hte samples seem a bit old? I'd really like something for the latest version of silverlight/facebook API...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are working on posting some silverlight samples to the Facebook C# SDK on Codeplex in the next week or so. You can find that SDK at http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com or http://www.microsoft.com/facebook. We will have an in browser and out of browser sample. For now, we have other samples on there that you can look at. For the most part the SDK works the same on any .Net platform.

Comment: Any progress on those samples? I'm struggling to achieve the same thing. Regards - Maciek

Comment: Are you docs extremely out of date? I am looking at your code samples and they use a 'get' method which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a SL application with facebook integration that utilizes. I use the [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) to log the user in, then pass the access_token into my SL app via a ScriptableMember method. I then use the FacebookApp constructor that takes an access token to create a new Facebook App object. Then I can make my calls directly from the SL app, without the need for a server-side proxy.

One thing to note, in your Facebook applicaiton settings, just enter http://localhost/ without the port for your site address.

I'm eagerly awaiting a little more guidance from Nathan, as he's a developer of the C# SDK